# EF How to seed a table with references to other tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, seeding

I've got the following Models:

```
[Table("SGDB_Persons")]
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SourceType SourceType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual PersonData PersonData { get; set; }
}
```

-

```
[Table("SGDB_Departments")]
public class Department {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Costcenter { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string FullDepartmentName {
        get {
            return $@"{Division.Abbreviation}\{Abbreviation}";
        }
    }
    [Required]
    public virtual Division Division { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return FullDepartmentName;
    }
}
```

-

```
[Table("SGDB_Users")]
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public string Domain { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SourceType SourceType { get; set; }
}
```

I'm seeding my Person (and related) tables with this piece of code:

```
protected override void Seed(PersonContext context) {
        var dep = new Department() {
            Abbreviation = "ICO2",
            Costcenter = "890",
            Description = "Information, Coordination and Organization 2",
            Division = new Division() {
                Abbreviation = "SG",
                Description = "Startermotors and Generators",
                PayrollArea = "220"
            }
        };
        var status = new Status {
            StatusType = "Test"
        };
        var persondata = new PersonData {
            Status = status,
            Limit = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1),
            Responsible = null
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var person = new Person {
                Firstname = $"TestPersonFirstname{i}",
                Lastname = $"TestPersonLastname{i}",
                SourceType = COM.SourceType.Manual,
                Department = dep,
                PersonData = persondata
            };
            context.Persons.Add(person);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

In the past I tried to retrieve some data (such as Departmens) from the database when seeding (creating a new instance of the DepartmentContext and calling the Get Method). This created a metadata exception. As you can see I resolved this by creating all required data inside the person seeding.

Now I want to seed some Users - the User Model contains a Person as a navigation property. I'd like to do something like this:

```
 protected override void Seed(UserContext context) {

        var person = new PersonContext().Persons.First();

        var user = new User() {
            Domain = "DE",
            Person = person,
            SourceType = COM.SourceType.Manual,
            UserID = "ThisIsATest"
        };
        context.Users.Add(user);

        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

But as I said this throws an exception. If possible I don't want to include the whole Person seeding process into the User seeding process - instead I want to get the first dataset out of the database (like code example)

Comment: you could create a context explicitly for reading, you'd just have to configure it properly, then you could set the initalizer to null and let EF do solely connection management, query creation and object materialization.